# chrome.tabs.update not working with mailto

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to launch outlook with

```
`chrome.tabs.update({"url":"mailto:example@example.com"});`
```

but it doesnt work

However, it works when I use this

```
chrome.tabs.create({"url":"mailto:example@example.com"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the tab you are updating. Try the following instead:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {"url":"mailto:example@example.com"});
});
```